# what does this mean? what string will be matched using the expression?

Tags: regex, sizzle

I checked the sizzle code and see a definition.

```
var chunker = /((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)+\)|\[(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]*['"]|[^\[\]'"]+)+\]|\\.|[^ >+~,(\[\\]+)+|[>+~])(\s*,\s*)?((?:.|\r|\n)*)/g,
```

I want to know how to find out what string(s) this regular expression will match?

Comment: The first time I saw a reverse question on regex.

Comment: Why the downvote and the close votes? If this piece of work was actually standing there uncommented, then this is a valid question

Comment: I don't even believe this regex is valid (looks like it's a parenthesis-pairing off)

Comment: @BradChristie: It is valid in JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this article](http://codejumble.blogspot.de/2011/01/sizzle-chunker.html). Explanation in a multiline regex:

```
var chunker = /
 (
  (?:
   # One or more sets of parentheses that contain a string, or another set of 
   parentheses with a string
   \(
   (?:
    \([^()]+\)
    |
    [^()]+
   )+
   \)
   |
   # Or one or more sets of brackets that contain a string, or another set of
   brackets with a string
   \[
   (?:
    \[[^\[\]]*\]
    |
    ['"][^'"]*['"]
    |
    [^\[\]'"]+
   )+
   \]
   |
   # Or a backslash followed by any character
   \\.
   |
   # Or one or more of any except these characters: > +~,([\
   [^ >+~,(\[\\]+
  )+
  # or any one of these characters: >+~
  |
  [>+~]
 )
 # followed by zero or one commas, which may be surrounded by whitespace
 (\s*,\s*)?
 # followed by zero or more of anything, including line endings
 ((?:.|\r|\n)*)
/g
```

This expression contains three matching groups: A "validated" selector expression, eventual comma, and everything after that. It will continuosly be called on the selector to split it up in parts, see the `Sizzle` constructor for details.

Answer (score 1):

It would be speculative. However, using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) you can 'document' and visualize the expression.

[image: Documentation using RegexBuddy]

Because it is a paid application i've exported the comments on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1cTHvpRs). Hope this will help you. (Note that it does not support Sizzle and that i've used JavaScript language to document the expression).

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to do it by hand, you can simply break it down like this (this is a task that will surely help you in the future):

```
var chunker = /((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)+\)|\[(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]*['"]|[^\[\]'"]+)+\]|\\.|[^ >+~,(\[\\]+)+|[>+~])(\s*,\s*)?((?:.|\r|\n)*)/g,
```

The first part is to know how a regex is generally written, so in this case it would be:

```
var variableName = /stuff/g;
                   ^  ^  ^^
        delimiters/---+--/|
                      |   |
                regex /   \global modifier, can also have a case modifier
```

So let's strip away the modifier and the start and end and evaluate just the regex:

```
((?:\((?:\([^()]+\)|[^()]+)+\)|\[(?:\[[^\[\]]*\]|['"][^'"]*['"]|[^\[\]'"]+)+\]|\\.|[^ >+~,(\[\\]+)+|[>+~])(\s*,\s*)?((?:.|\r|\n)*)
```

Still gobbledygook, but let's continue: The regex is for *capturing content* and we know that unescaped (meaning they use a backslash before the character being escaped `\`) parenthesis are capturing braces, let's add some newlines around each parenthesis (only for the purposes of examination!!!) and pipes mean "or"

```
(
  (?:
    \(
      (?:
          \(
              [^()]+
          \)
        |
          [^()]+
      )+
    \)
|
  \[
    (?:
        \[[^\[\]]*\]
      |
        ['"][^'"]*['"]
      |
        [^\[\]'"]+
    )+
  \]
|
  \\.
|
  [^ >+~,
  (
      \[\\]+)+
    |
      [>+~]
  )
  (\s*,\s*)?
  (
    (?:
        .
      |
        \r
      |
        \n
    )*
  )
```

Square braces mean "selectively match what is inside of this as any value from a choice-set" and so now I'm going to add a few comments, and let you work out the rest (also, it does look like some parens are missing)

```
(
  (?:                 //<-- start a non-capturing group (means, don't tell the app we matched)
    \(
      (?:             //<-- start a non-capturing group (means, don't tell the app we matched)
          \(
              [^()]+  //one or more paren pairs inside a paren pair
          \)
        |
          [^()]+      //or one or more paren pairs
      )+
    \)
|
  \[
    (?:
        \[[^\[\]]*\]
      |
        ['"][^'"]*['"]
      |
        [^\[\]'"]+
    )+
  \]
|
  \\.
|
  [^ >+~,
  (
      \[\\]+)+
    |
      [>+~] //either a tilde, plus or opening brace
  )
  (\s*,\s*)?
  (
    (?:
        .
      |
        \r
      |
        \n
    )*
  )
```